# Unique session issue with Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, ajax, session, cross-domain, access-control

When I am trying to access data using cross Domain request (from multiple domains).

I have added the following codes in php file at back end.

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Every time a new session is generated for each request, because of which large number of session files pile up on server. How to manage this in PHP.

How I can stop to create new session on each request?
OR
How can I clean the session on each request so that session files will not pile up on server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session_start() and session_destroy() works for cleaning session files . :)